# PHP Register script

Tags: php, refactoring, registration

So I'm trying to write this script for my site.
It looks quite messed up and broken.
Maybe somebody can help me tidy it up a bit and explain what might be incorrect.
Also, is there a way to make it shorter, looks a bit unsafe to me.
Thank you.

```
<?php

class Register
{
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $password2;
    private $passmd5;
    private $email;
    private $email2;

    private $errors;
    private $rtoken;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->errors = array();

        $this->username  = $this->filter($_POST['ruser']);
        $this->password  = $this->filter($_POST['rpass']);
        $this->password2 = $this->filter($_POST['rpass2']);
        $this->email     = $this->filter($_POST['remail']);
        $this->email2    = $this->filter($_POST['remail2']);
        $this->rtoken    = $_POST['rtoken'];

        $this->passmd5 = md5($this->password);
    }

    public function process()
    {
        if ($this->valid_rtoken() && $this->valid_data())
            $this->register();

        return count($this->errors) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public function filter($var)
    {
        return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9@.]/', '', $var);
    }
    public function register()
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(username,password,email) VALUES ('{$this->username}','{$this->passmd5}','{$this->email}')");

        if (mysql_affected_rows() < 1)
            $this->errors[] = '<font color="red">Database error</font>';
    }

    public function user_exists()
    {
        $data = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM users WHERE username = '{$this->username}'");

        return mysql_num_rows($data) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    public function email_exists()
    {
        $data = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM users WHERE email = '{$this->email}'");

        return mysql_num_rows($data) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    public function show_errors()
    {
        echo "";

        foreach ($this->errors as $key => $value)
            echo $value . "<br>";
    }

    public function valid_data()
    {
        if ($this->user_exists())
            $this->errors[] = '<font color="red">Username Exists</font>';
        if ($this->email_exists())
            $this->errors[] = '<font color="red">email exists</font>';
        if (empty($this->username))
            $this->errors[] = '<font color="red">check your username</font>';
        if (empty($this->password))
            $this->errors[] = '<font color="red">check your password</font>';
        if ($this->password != $this->password2)
            $this->errors[] = '<font color="red">Passwords do not match</font>';
        if (empty($this->email) || !eregi('^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$', $this->email))
            $this->errors[] = '<font color="red">Check your email</font>';
        if ($this->email != $this->email2)
            $this->errors[] = '<font color="red">Emails do not match</font>';

        return count($this->errors) ? 0 : 1;
    }


    public function valid_rtoken()
    {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['rtoken']) || $this->rtoken != $_SESSION['rtoken'])
            $this->errors[] = '<font color="red">Check</font>';

        return count($this->errors) ? 0 : 1;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Some explanation of whats "quite messed up and broken" would be helpful.  Are you getting an error?  Is something not behaving as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swoosh, there are always better ways to write code. I hope to challenge you to rethink why your code is long, and why it might be unsafe, rather than rewrite your code for you. Hopefully you will learn more this way.

To begin with, hashing the password with MD5 is completely insecure. Please forget that MD5 ever existed, and please don't use even SHA1 for anything secure. Instead, you should use bcrypt or PBKDF2 (with SHA2 or Whirlpool and ~2000+ rounds). I suggest you refer to my answer to [Secure Hash and Salt for PHP Passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords/401684#401684) for tips and links to articles and libraries to help implement better security.

Second, mysql_* functions are [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) as of PHP 5.5. Using MySQLi will get you by, but you should use a consistent interface such as [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo) to handle the connections, and query escaping/filtering. While you might not be building your software in PHP 5.5, you will not always have control over if a host decides to upgrade your version of PHP. Optimize for future compatibility as much as you can now. Plus, PDO has some nifty features that are explained in [its documentation](http://www.php.net/pdo).

Third, you should not use a regular expression to "filter" your query variables. The safest thing you can do is use intval/floatval on any numbers, and escape the rest through the DB library you use such as [mysql_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_escape_string) (or [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string)) OR use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) (which will sanitize variables for you).

Fourth, you are putting display logic into your object. Think about it: what purpose/role does this object fulfill? Does it handle the registration logic? Does it store the registration data? It's a good idea to use the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/srp.pdf) here. It looks like the object is supposed to act like a hybrid model-controller, with presentational information in it. You could expand this to RegistrationModel and RegistrationController classes to handle storing the data temporarily, or even decide to do something else. But remember, the more responsibilities that your class has the more ways it'll have to break.

Also, by making all the attributes of Register private, you cannot have more than one way to register. What if you wanted a short-cut to the process, such as log in via OAuth (such as Twitter or Facebook), but needed to reuse some of the logic in Register? These attributes should at least be protected so that you can inherit from them, or even public so another object can interface with them (such as an object that notifies the user that their registration is successful).